# How can i open a custom ListView on the a choose index in the list

Tags: android

I have a long ListView of textView in an Activity , and i need when i am moving to the activity with the ListView to open it on the index that been chosen

Thanks for Helping!!!

Answer (score 0):

Send the index via intent and invoke `setSelection(index)` on your `ListView`.